# Is it possible to open a Word document in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, dom

I have the requirement that I need to open a document in Microsoft word processor from an ASP.NET application. So far I am able to show all the document, but I am not sure how I could  open a document in an ASP.NET application. Please advise and let me know how flexible it is in future perspective if in case I need to perform further operation like update and relocation etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

There are third-party components designed to process Office documents in a server environment.

Aspose is quite popular, though I have never used them personally

http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

**UPDATE**

Open XML is supported in ASP.Net applications and is a good option (though I believe Aspose may be easier to work with).  See @Seth's answer about Open XML, See @Rob's answer about experience with Aspose vs. Open XML.

Comment: Can you please see @seth reply and comment it please

Comment: I am not sure it is supportive in production level

Answer (score 1):

If the document is from Office 2007 or higher (docx, xlsx, etc), then you can work with the files programmatically in .Net.

Research [Office Open Xml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML).

Microsoft provides an [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx).

An example from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478255) is provided below:

```
WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = 
    WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true);

Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
run.AppendChild(new Text(txt));

wordprocessingDocument.Close();
```

Comment: Is it supportive in server production level

Comment: +1 Open XML is a good option and seems to be supported in ASP.Net apps based on the comments here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee945362(v=office.11).aspx `When building an ASP.NET application, you may want to create Open XML documents dynamically and serve them up to remote users`

Answer (score 1):

I have an Aspose.Total license which allows me to create Word, PDF docs, etc.  I initially tried Open XML but there wasn't enough examples to do what I needed.  Support for Office 2010 in the form of examples for Open XML are thin at best.  When it comes right down to it, why reinvent the wheel in a ton of code with Open XML (which if you code it yourself there is no production support) when you can purchase a library for $800 bucks? If I get paid $100 per hour and I take more than 8 hours to do what Aspose can do, I am loosing money.  My recommendation is that if you need production support for your app and want to get the project going today, try Aspose.

Comment: +1, that was my expectation but I didn't have the experience to back it up.